# Call a method inside a fragment when all UI elements are visible

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-fragments

Is there a way of calling a method inside a fragment once all UI elements are displayed? I am having trouble at the moment trying to figure out which method in the fragment lifecycle should I put my code in. Basically, I am waiting for some input on my socket by calling `inStream.read(buffer)` where `inStream` is an `inputStream` and buffer is a `byte[]` already initialised. My problem is that this call prevents the UI from being fully displayed whether I call it in onResume, onStart, onActivityCreated (it always waits until it has received something before the UI is fully displayed). Is there a specific fragment lifecycle method for this? (So the socket kinda works in the background just waiting for input instead of hogging the foreground, since the data received will be used to fill some textboxes in the UI of the fragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the UI Main thread who is responsible for drawing UI components, open and read your Socket in a separeated Thread like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I was reading the link and it mentioned that AsyncTask is used for tasks which execute for a few seconds at most...would this still be appropriate for my application? It could take a long time before the socket receives any input

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the socket. If you just want to open the socket and read one stream and close the socket afterwards, then you can use `AsynTask`. But if you want to make a bidirectional communication from your app to the server socket and vice versa, then `AsyncTask` is not a good choice. If so, you should write your own threading mechanism. In that case you could also consider to write a Service. `AsyncTask` is meant to do a single long running action in the background (`doInBackground()`) and do the result propagation on the main ui thread (`onPostExecute()`)

Comment: Is it possible to call an AsyncTask from the main activity while you are inside another fragment? (if so, how?)

Comment: Everything is possible, the question is: is it a good idea :D Why would you start the AsyncTask from Activity if you want to use the socket in the Fragment? You can start a AsyncTask wherever you want, it is not bound to activity or fragment. The only thing you have to keep in mind is to cancel the AsyncTask in `Activity.onDestor()` or `Fragment.onDestroyView()` to avoid leaks. Why not starting the AsyncTask in the Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

sockeqwe is spot on, you should perform that task in a separate thread so as not to block the UI thread.

To answer the question in the title in case anybody arrives here for that reason, a global layout listener can be used to get a callback when layout is complete. In `onCreateView` use any view in your layout:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // do whatever you need
        // remove the layout listener if not needed anymore
        removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(view, this);
    }
});
```

Here's a static helper method to remove the layout listener

```
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        removeLayoutListenerJB(v, victim);
    } else removeLayoutListener(v, victim);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void removeLayoutListenerJB(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(victim);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private static void removeLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim);
}
```